# How I can slow down animation while still refreshing at 60 fps?

Tags: javascript

i'm always struggled with animating and the idea of intervals/fps. I understand how the code works in this snippet but I just don't understand how I can slow down animation while still keep the canvas at 60 fps refresh rate.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 startAnimating(60);
});

//Global Variables
var fpsInterval;
var then;
var shift = 0;
var frameWidth = 107;
var frameHeight = 140;
var canvasX = 0;
var canvasY = 0;
var myImage = new Image();
var totalFrames = 8;
var currentFrame = 0;
//Loading image
myImage.src = "https://i.imgur.com/N3shTgD.png";
myImage.addEventListener("load", loadImage, false);
//Function to begin animation with set fps
function startAnimating(fps)
{
 fpsInterval = 1000/fps;
 then = Date.now();
 animate();
}

function animate() {

 var now = Date.now();
 var elapsed = now - then;

 if (elapsed > fpsInterval)
 {
  then = now - (elapsed % fpsInterval);
  var cvs = $("canvas").get(0);
  var ctx = cvs.getContext("2d");

  //clear background
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, cvs.width, cvs.height);
  //draw each frame and place in middle of canvas
  /*
  drawImage(
  "Image object",
  "X coordinate next sprite in png (Location of sprite?)",
  "Y coorinate next sprite in png",
  "Width of sprite in png (How big is sprite?)",
  "Height of sprite in png"
  "X coordinate on canvas (Where to draw it?)"
  "Y coordinate on canvas"
  "Sprite width to use (How you want it to look?)"
  "Sprite height to use"
  )
  */
  //(sprite.png,0,0,300,300,0,0,300,300)
  ctx.drawImage(myImage, shift, 0, frameWidth, frameHeight, canvasX, canvasY, frameWidth, frameHeight);
  shift += frameWidth + 1;
 }

 if (currentFrame == totalFrames) {
  shift = 0;
  currentFrame = 0;
 }
 currentFrame++;
 requestAnimationFrame(animate);
}
```

```html
<html>
 <head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <!-- What code do we need? -->
  <script src ="exercise_three.js"></script>
 </head>
 <body>
  <canvas width="300" height="300" style="border: solid black 1px">
   Sorry, no canvas support!
  </canvas>
 </body>
</html>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/r7dd2mt7/2/ `RequestAnimationFrame()`

I would greatly appreciate some help understanding how it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

60 FPS means that frames are changed every 1000 / 60 milliseconds (it is about 16.7 ms). So if you have only 8 frames (like in your example), the whole loop will take 133.3 ms. Of course it is too fast. You can slow it down in two ways:

- Increase the number of frames. The following example uses a sprite of 45 frames. Animation looks smoother and slower.

```js
//Global Variables
var fpsInterval;
var then;
var shift = 0;
var frameWidth = 397;
var frameHeight = 300;
var canvasX = 0;
var canvasY = 0;
var myImage = new Image();
var totalFrames = 45;
var currentFrame = 0;
//Loading image
myImage.onload = function() {
    startAnimating(60);
};
myImage.src = "https://i.imgur.com/u6uPigf.png";
//Function to begin animation with set fps
function startAnimating(fps) {
 fpsInterval = 1000/fps;
 then = Date.now();
 animate();
}

function animate() {
  var now = Date.now();
  var elapsed = now - then;
  if (elapsed > fpsInterval) {
    then = now - (elapsed % fpsInterval);
    var cvs = $("canvas").get(0);
    var ctx = cvs.getContext("2d");
    //clear background
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, cvs.width, cvs.height);
    //draw each frame and place in middle of canvas
    /*
    drawImage(
    "Image object",
    "X coordinate next sprite in png (Location of sprite?)",
    "Y coorinate next sprite in png",
    "Width of sprite in png (How big is sprite?)",
    "Height of sprite in png"
    "X coordinate on canvas (Where to draw it?)"
    "Y coordinate on canvas"
    "Sprite width to use (How you want it to look?)"
    "Sprite height to use"
    )
    */
    ctx.drawImage(myImage, shift, 0, frameWidth, frameHeight, canvasX, canvasY, frameWidth, frameHeight);
    shift += frameWidth + 1;
    currentFrame++;
    if (currentFrame == totalFrames) {
        shift = 0;
        currentFrame = 0;
    }
  }
 requestAnimationFrame(animate);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<canvas width="300" height="300" style="border: solid black 1px">
  Sorry, no canvas support!
</canvas>
```

- If you want to use only given 8 frames, then the only way is to decrease the FPS value. For example, here is the 10 FPS version. Not so smooth but still looks acceptable.

```js
//Global Variables
var fpsInterval;
var then;
var shift = 0;
var frameWidth = 107;
var frameHeight = 140;
var canvasX = 0;
var canvasY = 0;
var myImage = new Image();
var totalFrames = 8;
var currentFrame = 0;
//Loading image
myImage.onload = function() {
  startAnimating(10);
}
myImage.src = "https://i.imgur.com/N3shTgD.png";
//Function to begin animation with set fps
function startAnimating(fps) {
 fpsInterval = 1000/fps;
 then = Date.now();
 animate();
}

function animate() {
  var now = Date.now();
  var elapsed = now - then;
  if (elapsed > fpsInterval) {
    then = now - (elapsed % fpsInterval);
    var cvs = $("canvas").get(0);
    var ctx = cvs.getContext("2d");
    //clear background
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, cvs.width, cvs.height);
    //draw each frame and place in middle of canvas
    /*
    drawImage(
    "Image object",
    "X coordinate next sprite in png (Location of sprite?)",
    "Y coorinate next sprite in png",
    "Width of sprite in png (How big is sprite?)",
    "Height of sprite in png"
    "X coordinate on canvas (Where to draw it?)"
    "Y coordinate on canvas"
    "Sprite width to use (How you want it to look?)"
    "Sprite height to use"
    )
    */
    ctx.drawImage(myImage, shift, 0, frameWidth, frameHeight, canvasX, canvasY, frameWidth, frameHeight);
    shift += frameWidth + 1;
    currentFrame++;
    if (currentFrame == totalFrames) {
        shift = 0;
        currentFrame = 0;
    }
  }
 requestAnimationFrame(animate);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<canvas width="300" height="300" style="border: solid black 1px">
  Sorry, no canvas support!
</canvas>
```

Comment: Woooow it all make sense now. Greatly appreciate!

Comment: @PiotrZadka I was glad to help

Answer (score 0):

There is an alternative that is simple. Rather than changing all your sprites, you can simple slow down your animation by adding a timeout. Effectively skipping paint frames in order to paint at your pace rather than the frame painting pace of the browser.

In the sample I removed all the cruft and added a pace variable. Set it in ms that you want each step to take (500 steps every 1/2 sec).  Note the setTimeout() call.

Just for fun, I also run your animation with setInterval because I was curious.

Check this:

```js
//Global Variables
var shift = 0;
var frameWidth = 107;
var frameHeight = 140;
var myImage = new Image();
var totalFrames = 8;
var currentFrame = 0;
var left = document.getElementById('left');
var leftCtx = left.getContext("2d");
var right = document.getElementById('right');
var rightCtx = right.getContext("2d");

// in ms, so 500 == 1 step every 1/2 second
var pace = 250;

myImage.src = "https://i.imgur.com/N3shTgD.png";
setInterval(rightStep, pace);
requestAnimationFrame(leftStep);

function leftStep() {
  leftCtx.clearRect(0, 0, left.width, left.height);
  leftCtx.drawImage(myImage, shift, 0, frameWidth, frameHeight, 0, 0, frameWidth, frameHeight);
  shift += frameWidth + 1;
  if(shift === (frameWidth * 8) + 8) {
   shift = 0;
  }
  setTimeout(stepLeftAgain, pace);
}

function stepLeftAgain(){
  requestAnimationFrame(leftStep);
}

function rightStep() {
  rightCtx.clearRect(0, 0, right.width, right.height);
  rightCtx.drawImage(myImage, shift, 0, frameWidth, frameHeight, 0, 0, frameWidth, frameHeight);
  shift += frameWidth + 1;
  if(shift === (frameWidth * 8) + 8) {
   shift = 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <canvas id="left" width="300" height="300" style="border: solid black 1px"></canvas>
    <canvas id="right" width="300" height="300" style="border: solid black 1px"></canvas>
  </body>
</html>
```